# How can I show only values in PHP table where column is NULL?

Tags: php, mysql

My code does not work and I can't figure out why

```
public function fetch_active_table_data(){
        $query = "SELECT id, name, location, admission, drink_prices, Performer FROM drinkdeals WHERE admission IS NULL";
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array("0"));
```

I am trying to just show the events where admission is null. What am I doing wrong? Thanks, Kieran
edit: It does work btw, when I remove the `WHERE admission IS NULL` so I know that's where the problem is. thanks

Comment: Do you have entries set at NULL? Is your default (column) value NULL?

Comment: Where is placeholder?

Comment: You could also try `WHERE admission = 'NULL'` but I doubt that'll work; but have a go at it.

Comment: Sorry, You can see here for before I put in NUll http://drinkdealsapplicationdublin.net78.net/android/index.php  and here for afterwards http://drinkdealsapplicationdublin.net78.net/viewdeals/

Comment: Then you may need to do `WHERE admission = ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you've set the value. Maybe you should try to look for an empty value like:

```
public function fetch_active_table_data(){
    $query = "SELECT id, name, location, admission, drink_prices, Performer FROM drinkdeals WHERE admission=''";
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array("0"));
}
```

Comment: Somehow didn't see this answer first. this was correct!

Comment: I wonder why it's been downvoted. By the way, yeah, good for you ;)

Comment: I am wondering why it's been downvoted too. I will +1 to round it off.

Comment: The/a reason that someone downvoted your answer might be that, when you say "Maybe you should try...", it doesn't sound reassuring as to why OP's code might be failing. Although this fixed the problem, it's usually best to first comment under OP's question; which is what I do first before making a comment to answer/answer.

Comment: I could not comment anywhere at the time of this answer(didn't have reached 50 points), but thanks anyway for the tip ;)